# Is "All hyperreal fields $C(\mathbb{R})/M$ are isomorphic" independent of ZFC+$\lnot$CH?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, reverse-math, nonstandard-analysis, ordered-fields

We work in ZFC.

Let $C(X)$ be the ring of continuous functions $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$, and $M$ a maximal ideal. We call $C(X)/M$ a hyperreal field if it's not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

A field $E$ is called real-closed if it has unique ordering $x\geq 0$ iff $\exists_{y\in E}\ x = y^2$ and all polynomials of odd degree have a root.

An ordered field $E$ is called an $\eta_1$-field if for all countable $A, B\subseteq E$ such that $A < B$ there is $x\in E$ such that $A < v < B$.

All hyperreal fields are real-closed $\eta_1$-fields.

We have the following result:

**Theorem.** Assume CH. Then all real-closed $\eta_1$-fields of size continuum are isomorphic.

**Corollary.** Assume CH. Then all hyperreal fields of size continuum are isomorphic.

Let P be "All hyperreal fields $C(\mathbb{R})/M$ are isomorphic".

I'm wondering if one can get some insight into what kind of statement is P in relation to known set-theoretic principles.

Is P independent of ZFC+$\lnot$CH? Above theorem shows that ZFC+CH implies P.

Note: The choice of $X = \mathbb{R}$ was arbitrary, to not consider *every* possible topological space $X$ such that $C(X)/M$ is a hyperreal field of size continuum. If this is helpful, please consider a different space $X$ instead.

Comment: $X = \mathbb R$ in $C(X)/M$?  Also, your **Theorem** mentions restricting to size-continuum fields, but your other statements do not.  Is that intentional?

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean, all hyperreal fields of the form $C(\mathbb{R})/M$ are of size continuum.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453036/how-strong-is-the-statement-all-hyperreal-fields-c-mathbbr-m-are-isomorph#comment1171856_453036), I was confused because your original version referred only to $C(\mathbb R)$.  I now see that the restriction to size continuum in the **Theorem** is necessary because you want to speak of hyperreal fields obtained by taking quotients of rings of continuous functions on other spaces.

Comment: @LSpice yes, I'm sorry, I was wondering how general should my question be, and decided on restricting to $X = \mathbb{R}$ after all. It was a typo I didn't clean from the initial version

Comment: Since ZFC+CH is equiconsistent with ZFC alone, what is the sense of strength that you intend in the question? Your hypothesis has no extra consistency strength, if it is implied by CH, since CH has none.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Oh, I'm sorry I didn't mean in terms of consistency strength, but rather what general set-theoretic principles imply it, and which refute it. Let me know how I can phrase this question better.

Comment: These issues are subtler than they may look at first pass; there is the consistency strength hierarchy, proof theoretic ordinal analysis, and reverse mathematics to consider for questions like this; see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355384/how-to-understand-the-interface-of-the-consistency-strength-hierarchy-reverse-m) for an excellent question by Tim highlighting possible interactions. It seems like what you’re looking for is closest to the reverse mathematics of your statement about hyperreal fields.

Comment: It seems to me that the natural question here is whether it is consistent to have not CH, yet all such hyperreal fields still isomorphic. I believe this will be possible.

Comment: @Jakobian The phrase "set-theoretic strength" suggests consistency strength, but you just want to know how your hypothesis interacts with other set-theoretic principles. I don't expect any implication from MA, and diamond implies CH anyway. One should instead be asking about consistency results, starting with: is your principle consistent with not CH? One could also ask about how naturally to force your statement or counterexamples, etc.

Comment: When you say that under ZF+CH, all C(*X*)/M are isomorphic, can we assume that means for a fixed topological space X ?

Comment: @DanielAsimov No, $X$ isn't fixed, if $C(X)/M$ and $C(Y)/N$ are hyperreal fields of size continuum, then they are isomorphic. In other words, there exists a unique smallest hyperreal field.

Comment: If $\frak{b}<\frak{d}$, then it seems we can get copies of the hyperreals with different cofinalities, hence not isomorphic. But under MA they will all have the same cofinality. So perhaps an MA connection is reasonable after all.

Comment: What exactly is the relationship between this construction of hyperreal fields and ultrapower constructions of hyperreal fields? I believe ultrapowers can be understood as a special case of this, but is the converse true as well?

Comment: If $X=\omega$ with the discrete topology, then we seem to get exactly the ultrapowers of $\mathbb{R}$ with a countable index set. I don't have a good sense for what happens in nondiscrete spaces $X$.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins my answer below applies to many spaces, certainly normal ones: if you have an infinite closed and discrete subset then you have a closed copy of $\mathbb{N}$ in your space and every ultrafilter $u$ on $\mathbb{N}$ yields a maximal ideal $M_u$ in $C(X)$. And $C(X)/M_u$ is the ultrapower of $\mathbb{N}$ by $u$.

Comment: @KPHart Yes, thanks! Very nice. I was surprised to learn that $\neg$CH is enough, since I had thought one needed to do work to get ultrafilters realizing different ultrapowers. Good to know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In [On ultra powers of Boolean algebras](http://topology.nipissingu.ca/tp/reprints/v09/tp09205.pdf) (Topology Proceedings 9 (1984) 269-291) Alan Dow proved (Corollary 2.3) that $\neg\mathsf{CH}$ implies there are two fields of the form $C(\mathbb{N})/M$ that are not isomorphic (as ordered sets, and hence as ordered fields).

To be a bit more precise: Alan constructed two ultrafilters $u$ and $v$ on $\mathbb{N}$ with non-isomorphic ultrapowers. These yield maximal ideals $M_u$ and $M_v$ in $C(\mathbb{N})$ whose quotients are (isomorphic to) the respective ultrapowers. And because $\mathbb{N}$ is a closed discrete subspace of the metric space $\mathbb{R}$ these determine maximal ideals $N_u$ and $N_v$ in $C(\mathbb{R})$ whose quotients are isomorphic to those by $M_u$ and $M_v$ respectively.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much! So the statement "all hyperreal fields of size continuum are isomorphic" is actually equivalent to CH. That's surprising.

Comment: I meant $\mathbb{N}$ because the question allowed for different spaces. But in this particular case an ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$ determines maximal ideals in $C(\mathbb{N})$ and in $C(\mathbb{R})$, whose quotients are isomorphic anyway.

Comment: I seem vaguely to remember that Shelah has a paper where he estimates the number of non-isomorphic ultrapowers modulo the negation of CH, but I can't seem to locate this right now.  Does this ring the bell?

Comment: Yes, the paper is cited in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/836784/72694

Comment: Apparently, according to one of the answers in the cited question, in ZFC+$\lnot$CH there is always $2^\mathfrak{c}$ non-isomorphic hyperreal fields $C(\mathbb{N})/M$. So when there is no uniqueness, the uniqueness fails completely!